# Mobx : Is there a way to find whether a form isDirty using a mobx Utility

Tags: javascript, mobx

Is there a way to find whether a form isDirty using a mobx Utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `createViewModel` from [**mobx-utils**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#user-content-createviewmodel):

```
class Todo {
  @observable title = "Test";
}

const model = new Todo();
const viewModel = createViewModel(model);

viewModel.title = "Get tea";
console.log(viewModel.isDirty); // true
```

For a complete MobX form solution you could check out [**mobx-react-form**](https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form) which has support for checking `isDirty` on fields.

Comment: Tholle , Do you have an example for this createViewModel using in a areact component

Comment: @Kamaraju I don't have a React example, sadly. Maybe you could get some inspiration from [**the documentation**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#createviewmodel)?